# What is the difference between an immortalized human cell line and a cancerous cell line?

Tags: cell-biology, cancer, mammalian-cell-culture

Many cell lines (like CaCo2) are derived from cancerous tissue, and hence, like any other tumor cell, they have an infinite replicative potential. However, many cell lines like HaCaT cells are not cancerous but still have infinite replicative potential.

*What makes a spontaneously transformed immortalized non-cancerous cell line different from a cancerous cell line?*

*What are the key differences in phenotype/genotype/karyotype? How are they different in origin?*

Comment: "This HaCaT cell line is obviously immortal (>140 passages), has a transformed phenotype in vitro (clonogenic on plastic and in agar) but remains nontumorigenic."

-Normal Keratinization in a Spontaneously Immortalized Aneuploid Human Keratinocyte Cell Line (Boukamp et al., 1988)